# Problems in logging into Launchpad and Ubuntu One

Tags: launchpad

I can't log into Ubuntu One because of my Launchpad account, which I don't remember.  So how can I straighten out this validation mess?  Really, I just want to use Pastebin.

I seem to be caught in some kind of validation
loop.  If I try to reset my password, I'm told that I already have a Launchpad account after I go through the reset-password loop yet again.

Comment: If you remember at least the email you can ask for a password reset. If not even that then register a new account.

Comment: DoI set the password for  Ubuntu One or for Launchpad? They seem to be related, but I don't understand how they are related.

Comment: Same account (Ubuntu SSO)